# In magento, new order email not working

Tags: email, magento

In magento, new order email not working but "Email to Friend" is working. I have set up "store email addresses" also, not working.

Kindly help

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: Did you update magento to latest version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a magento cron job on the server. this will trigger order emails.

thank you